# Determining and enforcing linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assuming we have a large set of multi-dimensional vectors (20k vectors, 100 dimensions each). My questions are the following:

- How can we determine the *level* of linear dependence of this set? Is there any appropriate technique or metric for this task?
- How can we convert this set of vectors to the closest possible set of *linearly independent* vectors? (by "closest possible set" I mean the set that preserves as much as possible the direction of the original vectors). Is there any method for this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This set must be linearly dependent. As a measure of linear dependence. I would look at the dimesnion of the span of these vectors. The higher the dimesnion the less linearly dependent they are

Comment: The only method of which I am aware (and it's not pretty): Take first vector: if it's dependent on what's already in the set, discard it, else put it into set. Go to next vector, repeat. If these are *random* vectors then you can say with near certainty that there will be exactly 100 independent vectors in the set.

Comment: What does "the closest possible set of ..." mean? "Close" how? "the"? is there only one?

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you for pointing this out, I have modified my question

Comment: I appreciate the edit, but it did not really explain what measure of "close" you are using. Do you have a particular one in mind?

Comment: It is cosine distance, sorry but since I mentioned "direction" I assumed this as evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At worst, you can just perform row reduction on the set, adding one new thing to test at a time.

You start with a nonzero vector, and store it in a matrix. Then, you find the next nonzero vector $v_2$ and try to get it into row-echelon form.

Each time you succeed in getting row-echelon form, you append the next nonzero vector to the bottom of the matrix and try to make it row-echelon again. If the row turns into zeros you reject that vector you added, if it's not zero, you accept the vector and continue. At the end, the number of rows of your big matrix is the dimension of the span of those $20$k vectors.

In theory, you would need to proceed until

- you collect 100 vectors in storage or
- you exhaust the supply of 20k vectors

whichever comes first! (Obviously the dimension of the span is bounded by $100$, since they all come from $F^{100}$ over whatever field you're thinking of.)

As someone mentioned, if the vectors are random, it is very likely you'll find 100 independent vectors long before you exhaust the supply.

Comment: Thank you very much, please read the modified question. I need to retain as much as possible the direction of the original vectors, I don't want them to be orthogonal.

Comment: @dkar You don't have to store the orthogonal vectors, this is just a means to see if they are independent or not. Added some more stuff to try to clarify that.

Comment: Thank you, that was very informative.